# Best_in_place - Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'elastic'

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, textarea, best-in-place

I am using the Best in place gem for editing a simple form in my rails app. When I change type to `textarea` I am getting the following error.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'elastic'
```

Here's the code:

```
<%= best_in_place @user, :summary, :type => :textarea %>
```

`best_in_place` editing is working fine for all other fields, however, `teaxtarea` fields will not update.

Here's my asset pipeline:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require foundation
//= require jquery.purr
//= require_tree .
//= require best_in_place
```

Anyone have any ideas as to how I can fix this?

Comment: Are you using JQuery elastic?

Comment: No, I assumed that .elastic() was included in the JQuery library. best_in_place.js calls .elastic() on the textarea.

Comment: Don't assume. Check it by yourself, there is none. http://api.jquery.com/

Comment: Good point. I looked into it and it turns out that elastic script is included with the best_in_place gem. I even added the elastic script gem to my gemfile. Still no luck...